# Adding a CSS class to jQuery window.location click

Tags: jquery

I wish to add a CSS class="XX" to the below?  How to do it?

```
click: function(marker){window.location = link}
```

Comment: May I ask what is the point of appending a CSS class to an element after redirecting the user to another page?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
click:function(marker){ window.location = link; $(marker).addClass('XX'); }
```

If it doesn't work, try this:

```
click:function(marker){ window.location = link; $(this).addClass('XX'); }
```

If it still doesn't work then I'm really sorry.